# Not gaining reputation on upvoted answers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, up-votes

I do not seem to be gaining reputation on upvoted answers. The most recent answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087183/does-any-language-have-a-delayed-return-mechanism/18087224#18087224) (which I have never received reputation from), and I am seeing similar new behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027874/is-there-an-idiom-for-adding-a-trailing-slash-to-a-file-path/18027897#18027897) (which used to be fine until recently). The questions are open and active, the answers have not been deleted (these are the reasons I found when searching for other reports like this).

The upvotes are listed on my reputation page, but the number next to it is blank. I have received reputation for correctly answered questions since, it seems to be either unique to these two questions, or unique to upvotes.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the repcap. :)

Comment: Ah OK. I was wondering if it was something like that but thought I should report it anyways. Thanks! I don't know if "bug" reports like this one are common, but if they are, adding a message to the rep page stating that the cap was hit might help reduce them.

Comment: The linked duplicate contains details about reputation and how it works - the reputation cap is the relevant bit here ;)

Comment: Thank you for posting that!

Comment: Incidentally, I just hit my daily voting limit too. Curse you all for limiting my excuses to procrastinate.

Comment: @Jason Heh :P Now you have to do something *productive*! ...what's that? :P